# Explanation about how to get a linear equation given a problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have issues getting the linear equation of this kind of problem, can you explain to me what do I need first and why? I can't understand properly to my teacher, please

The owner of a bottled water franchise must pay $ 500 per month, plus 5% of the monthly income (I) for the use of the brand.

```
A) Determine the monthly expenses (E) in terms of (I)

B) How much should you pay if you had a monthly income of $ 15,450?
```

NOTE: I need an explanation about how to get the equation not to solve it, thank you

Comment: Forget linear equation. Can you write a formula for $E$ in terms of $I$? In other words, let's say that my monthly income is $I$. Can you tell me how much I have to pay?

Comment: It's hard to start explanation without knowing your level of understanding. What exactly is your issue here?

Comment: @YuriyS I just want to know how to get an equation from that and why that way?

Comment: Can you answer question B?

Comment: The equation is "Expenses equals \$500 plus 5% percent of Income".  So if "Income" equals \$15,450$ the equation is "Expenses equals \$500 plus 5% of \$15,450".... Math *can* be written in "English" if we want.

Answer (score 0):

Well " must pay \$500 per month, plus...." so $E = 500 + .....$

"....plus 5% of the monthly income (I)".  So

$E = 500 + \text{5 % of } I$

and as "$x$% of K" means $\frac x{100}\cdot K$ we have

$E = 500 + \frac 5{100}I$.

That's it.  Ase $\frac 5{100} = \frac 1{20}$ we can rewrite it as $E = 500 +\frac 1{20}I$ but we don't have to.

That's A.

And B)

"How much should you pay (*in expenses*) if you had a monthly income of $ 15,450?"

Then Income $= I = 15450$.

So Expenses $=E = 500 + \frac {5}{100} I$ will be a matter of plugging in $I = 15450$.

$E = 500 + \frac 5{100}I =$

$500 + \frac 5{100}\cdot 15450$.

Which is what?

Comment: The asnwer is 1272.50